# Style text field with line

Tags: xcode

I'm looking for a way to create a text field that is just a line (png or something) and on that line the user can type.

What I have is a line (png) and set this as background off the text field. Then vertical align this so the line is in the bottom.

It is almost what I want to achieve, only the text is floating a bit.

[image: Text floating on line]

Someone could help me?

Working in xCode btw.

Comment: Can you show your code for your field?

Comment: I'm working with the storyboard in xCode 5. So I don't have any code written for the field in my view controller. I just have an outlet.

Comment: ughh, sorry no idea then

Comment: Can you show me how to do it in code? I can change this from storyboard to code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by using UITextField and UIImage.
1) UITextField with 
BorderStyle: UITextBorderStyleNone
Vertical Alignment : UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom
2)Place UIImage right bellow the text field and add line.png